# Neutral points of a point charge

Tags: electrostatics

How many points exist at which electrostatic field due to a point charge is zero?
Clearly we have, due to a point charge Q,
$$\textbf E(r,\theta)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_{o}r^2}(\cos(\theta)\textbf i+\sin(\theta)\textbf j)$$
and
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\textbf E(r,\theta)=\textbf0$$
$$\forall\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$
Thus can we conclude there exists infinitely many points at an infinite radial distance from a point charge where the electric field is zero? Is this okay?

Comment: You need to be careful using infinity in calculations. The limit of the field as $r \rightarrow \infty$ is indeed zero, but that's just a limit. If you consider a single charge in its own universe there is nowhere in the universe where the field is zero.

Comment: So we can't say what happens at $\infty$? and we can only talk about as $\infty$ is approached?

Comment: We can say that as $r$ approaches $\infty$, $\textbf E$ approaches $\textbf 0$, but exactly what happens at $\infty$ is undefined, is that right?

Comment: Yes, or at least that is the position I would take. I suspect most physicists believe no real quantity is ever infinite, with the possible exception of the size of the universe though even that is contentious.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to say *what happens at $\infty$ is undefined*. The field has a well defined limit - it's just that you could never reach that limit.

Comment: Yes, we can never reach the limit, but theoretically such points of neutrality exist? We have a mathematically well defined limit. I'm not talking about any physical interpretation, can then we say, that we have, mathematically, infinitely many points at which the $\textbf E$ is $\textbf 0$ or we are only good enough to say $\textbf E$ approaches $\textbf 0$ as r approaches $\infty$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is trivially 'Yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinitely distant points in three-dimensional space can be considered as none (i.e. "such concepts are not points at all"), one, or infinitely many.

The first interpretation is the most straightforward. From John Rennie's comment:

> The limit of the field as $r→∞$ is indeed zero, but that's just a limit. If you consider a single charge in its own universe there is nowhere in the universe where the field is zero.

But there are some *theoretical* concepts in mathematics that could apply:

- [Projectively extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectively_extended_real_line) for one dimension, [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) for two; this can be generalized for more dimensions. They treat infinity as a **single** point. Also compare: *[To put a point at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2365495/331040)*.
- [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) tells apart $-∞$ from $∞$, so there are two points at infinity in this case. Multi-dimensional generalization would be something like [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry) where points at infinity are considered different according to the directions of straight lines they belong to. This leads to **infinitely many** (uncountably many) points at infinity. I guess you have intuitively applied something similar in your conclusion.

My conclusion: the answer to your question depends on the theoretical concept of space you choose.

Comment: I thought about it this way: r can either take a large finite value or an infinite value.  For a large finite value, E is non zero and assigning an infinite value to r is not possible as infinity is not a number. So E is non zero for finite values and not really defined at infinity. We can only say E approaches 0 as r approaches infinity. If E was 0 at infinity, we never would've needed a concept like limit. So there exists no points in the finite space, and since we can't evaluate for infinite distance, we don't talk about that.

Answer (score 0):

I now believe the answer to be no points. E is non zero for finite r>0 and since r can never reach infinity, we cannot talk about points at infinity. It would be just wrong to say we have infinitely many points where E is 0.